# CreateSharedMemory usage

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, shared-memory

Does anyone have an example of [CreateSharedMemory function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) usage? In a shared internal memory client/server software scenario the server input parameters to the function are only `MaxSize` and `InitialSize`, so just how can the client know what memory address is shared? [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) solves this since you [can name each file mapping object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I know that Boost has similar features, but I'm looking to solve this using the raw Windows API functionality.

Comment: `CreateFileMapping` is raw Windows API.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use `CreateSharedMemory` as it allocates internal memory on the heap while `CreateFileMapping` allocates file mapping objects (ie. virtual memory).

Comment: The CreateSharedMemory function is used for authentication purposes. In general, you should use page-file backed memory mapped files.

Comment: I'm not sure that `CreateSharedMemory` is what you want either. It's not obvious from the question what you are trying to do. It sounds like you are wanting memory shared across processes. That's not what `CreateSharedMemory` does as I understand it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you got confused by the "client" and "server" terminology on the page. Out of LSA (windows security) context it may seem that `CreateSharedMemory` does what you want. It does not: the function is designed and used only in a windows security and authentication context.

Despite the name, is not a (general purpose) function to allocate shared memory between two processes.

What you need, for sharing memory between processes is done (usually) by page-file backed memory mapped files, so through `CreateFileMapping` etc.
Other techniques exists, but I would recommend using page-file backed memory mapped files.